# Extract lines in file1 starting with a specific word given in file2

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep, extract

I have one file "file1" that contains lines like:

```
643 2   3   4   5
6433    2   3   4   5
64  2   3   4   5
1234    2   3   4   5
1240    2   3   4   5
12  2   3   4   5
```

and I would like to extract from it all lines whose first word contained in file 2, which is like:

```
12
64
```

Thus, the final result should be:

```
12  2   3   4   5
64  2   3   4   5
```

In bash I think I have to use a loop for examining each word in file 2, but I do not know the command to extract the line in file1 containing the exact word.

For example, using:

```
sed -n '/^64/p' file1
```

I get:

643 2   3   4   5
6433    2   3   4   5
64  2   3   4   5

which is not correct, because I would like only line:
64  2   3   4   5

Do you know a bash method (sed, grep, awk, or python if you prefer) to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]; next} $1 in a' file2 file1
64  2   3   4   5
12  2   3   4   5
```

Comment: `awk '$1 in a;a[$1]' file2 file1` , `awk 'a[$1]++' file2 file1`

Comment: Why do we need `;a[$1]` here?

Comment: So that it is created ? I don't know what you mean ?

Comment: Did you try above given `awk` command? Are you not getting same output as I showed in my answer?

Answer (score 3):

I'd say:

```
awk 'NR == FNR { a[$1] = 1; next } a[$1]' file2 file1
```

That is:

```
NR == FNR {    # while processing the first file (file2)
  a[$1] = 1    # remember what values you saw
  next         # do nothing else
}
a[$1]          # after that (while processing file1): print those whose first
               # field was seen in the pass over file2.
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try with grep -w and more exactly:

```
 -w    Searches for the expression as a word as if surrounded
       by \< and \>.
```

so yu can try:

```
grep -w 64 file1
```

Running on Solaris 10

Answer (score 0):

To use grep, but also add an anchor to the patterns in the search file:

```
grep -wf <(sed 's/^/^/' file2) file1
```